# How to concatenate strings with condition each loop in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, loops, concatenation, each

I'm trying to concatenate 2 consecutive strings if any string length is less than 4 characters, but I'm not successful.

The code I have so far is:

```
strings = ['abnhs', 'iuu', 'poioyw', 'tyr', 'mmkaud']
strings.each do |w|
  if w.length < 4
    temp = w
    next
  end    
  w = temp + w 
  puts w
end
```

Expected output is:

```
abnhs
iuupoioyw
tyrmmkaud
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: You know that this will overwrite some values if more than two strings in a row has less then 4 characters?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the temp variable outside of your each block. Try this:

```
strings = ['abnhs', 'iuu', 'poioyw', 'tyr', 'mmkaud']
temp = ''
strings.each do |w|
  if w.length < 4
    temp = w
    next
  end    
  w = temp + w 
  puts w
end
```